# How do I remove the parenthesis from my bs4 results

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping using requests, Beautifulsoup4, and django. The results work fine except I they are in closed in parenthesis. I How can I return them whithout parenthesis. heres my code:

My view
    url = ('http://www.vladtv.com/')

```
google = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(google.content, 'html.parser')
d = bs.title.string

a_links = bs.findAll('div', 'entry')

links = []
for link in a_links:
    links.append((
        link.text,

    )
)

# samples = soup.find_all("a", "item-title")
myset = set(links)
context = {
    "links": links,
}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

my template

```
{% for l in links %}
   {{l}}<br><hr>
{% endfor %}
```

my results

```
('251Drake Dethrones 50 Cent on Forbes Top Five Richest Hip-Hop Stars of 20168,787 views9 Hrs Ago',)

('175Kanye Claims Kim Kardashian Broke Boundaries for Biracial Couples5,923 views15 Hrs Ago',)

('94Stevie Wonder: If Michael Jackson is King of Pop, Prince is the Emperor4,482 views16 Hrs Ago',)
```

I want to display it like this

```
'251Drake Dethrones 50 Cent on Forbes Top Five Richest Hip-Hop Stars of 20168,787 views9 Hrs Ago',

'175Kanye Claims Kim Kardashian Broke Boundaries for Biracial Couples5,923 views15 Hrs Ago',

'94Stevie Wonder: If Michael Jackson is King of Pop, Prince is the Emperor4,482 views16 Hrs Ago',
```

How can this be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because *you are actually appending tuples* into the list. Replace:

```
links = []
for link in a_links:
    links.append((
        link.text,
    )
)
```

with:

```
links = [link.text for link in a_links]
```

Comment: That did it. I appreciate the time you took to answer me.

Comment: what if i wanted to do this 'for link in a_links:
        links.append((
            link.text,
            link.get('href'),
            link.get('src')
        )
    )'

Comment: @user3650429 okay, but what would be the desired output in this case? If you, say, want to comma-separate the items, you can do: `[",".join(item) for item in links]`..

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want the output to be *literally* as posted in question i.e including single-quotes and trailing comma, you can skip the first and the last characters to exclude the parentheses :

```
links = [str((link.text,))[1:-1] for link in a_links]
```

Comment: what if i wanted to do this 'for link in a_links:
        links.append((
            link.text,
            link.get('href'),
            link.get('src')
        )
    )' so that I could href and src